# UISearchBar inside a NavigationBar Get Deferenced When Keyboard Shows Up

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uisearchbar, uiappearance

I'm putting a search bar inside a navigation bar. here is the code

```
self.navigationBar =[[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 64)];
[self.view addSubview:self.navigationBar];

self.doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                           target:self
                                                           action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 64)];
self.searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Name of City";
self.searchBar.delegate = self;

self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsTitle = @"Add Location";
self.searchController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
self.searchController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[self.doneButton];
self.navigationBar.items = @[self.searchController.navigationItem];
```

but the search bar behaves incorrectly.

[image]

I'm expecting it would look like this
[image]

Comment: @ElGuapo the search box is not in front.  I've updated the question,  add the expected ui.

Comment: Is this Sol? I just saw the same problem when taking a look at the code. :D

Comment: @LeoNatan,Yes and I want to fix it. Any Idea how?

Comment: @fengd There were some changes introduced in that area. Make sure you rebase to the latest available code and see if it is better now.

Comment: @LeoNatan I believe it is the latest. I just downloaded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this by bring the `navigationBar` to front after setting `searchBar` as the first responder

```
[self.searchController setActive:YES animated:NO];
[self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.navigationBar]; //this is the line I add
```